# SQL query, how to separate it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

```
$query = 'SELECT newsvid.id, ......  videoinformation.imgShot3, videomain.vidMUrl FROM newsvid, videomain, videoinformation  WHERE newsvid.id = ' . $video_id . 'videoinformation.id =' . $video_id . ' newsvid.id = ' . $video_id;
```

Problem is HAVE NO IDEA how to make this bit work:

```
WHERE newsvid.id = ' . $video_id . 'videoinformation.id =' . $video_id . ' newsvid.id = ' . $video_id;
```

MAIN problem is that after this bit

```
WHERE newsvid.id = ' . $video_id
```

Nothing is working, so it's make newsvid.id = 1 BUT this bit

```
. 'videoinformation.id =' . $video_id . ' newsvid.id = ' . $video_id;
```

is not recognized as a query.... another words this bit is not part of sql query.

Currently SQL query understand only that for example newsvid.id is equal to 1 and I need that this query will understand that videoinformation.id and videomain.id are equal to 1 (video_id) as well

Finally this is working:

```
$query = 'SELECT newsvid.id, videoinformation.id, videomain.id, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.imgCover, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidQUality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidMaker, videoinformation.vidRoles, videoinformation.vidTime, videoinformation.imgShot1, videoinformation.imgShot2, videoinformation.imgShot3, videomain.vidMUrl FROM newsvid, videomain, videoinformation  WHERE newsvid.id = 1 AND videoinformation.id = 1 AND videomain.id = 1;
```

BUT insted of **"1"** I need $video_id.

Because I have php   `<?php $video_id = $_GET['id']; ?>`

FOR me helps

```
SELECT newsvid.id, videoinformation.id, videomain.id, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.imgCover, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidQUality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidMaker, videoinformation.vidRoles, videoinformation.vidTime, videoinformation.imgShot1, videoinformation.imgShot2, videoinformation.imgShot3, videomain.vidMUrl FROM newsvid, videomain, videoinformation WHERE newsvid.id = videoinformation.id AND newsvid.id = videomain.id AND newsvid.id = '. $video_id ;
```

Comment: Use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: how exactly in this case i can do it?

Comment: your question is not understandable... find a way to rephrase

Comment: Changed a bit, may be will be more understandable.

Comment: Yours doesn't work, this is the main problem I changed it soooo many time ... different ways but still .... ((( I edit my question... check it pls..

Comment: Using php where insted of video_id I will put 1 ... everything is working nicely... but(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT newsvid.id, ......  videoinformation.imgShot3, videomain.vidMUrl 
          FROM newsvid, videomain, videoinformation  
          WHERE newsvid.id = " . $video_id . " AND videoinformation.id =" . $video_id . "                
          AND newsvid.id = " . $video_id;
```

OR version:

```
$query = "SELECT newsvid.id, ......  videoinformation.imgShot3, videomain.vidMUrl 
          FROM newsvid, videomain, videoinformation  
          WHERE newsvid.id = " . $video_id . " OR videoinformation.id =" . $video_id .  "                
          OR newsvid.id = " . $video_id;
```

and tell us if either helped you.

If this still does not work, dump the $query and try it manually in phpmyadmin (or whatever interface you are using) and paste the error here.

**P.S** BE CAREFUL ON HOW COLUMNS IN EACH TABLE ARE NAMED!!!

**L.E:** this is your query

```
SELECT newsvid.id, videoinformation.id, videomain.id, newsvid.vidTitle, 
newsvid.imgCover, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidQUality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidMaker, videoinformation.vidRoles, videoinformation.vidTime, videoinformation.imgShot1, videoinformation.imgShot2, videoinformation.imgShot3, videomain.vidMUrl 
FROM newsvid, videomain, videoinformation 
WHERE newsvid.id = 1 AND videoinformation.id = 1 AND videomain.id = 1;
```

You are trying to select values from multiple tables, and for this, you need a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)(click for more details).

so your query should be:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM newsvid as nw
JOIN videomain as vm ON nw.id = vm.id
JOIN videoinformation as vi ON vi.id = vm.id
WHERE nw.id = video_id ;
```

in PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT ... 
FROM newsvid as nw
JOIN videomain as vm ON nw.id = vm.id
JOIN videoinformation as vi ON vi.id = vm.id
WHERE nw.id = ". $video_id ;
```

where nw, vm and vi are aliases for the tables and video_id is the FK for what I think is the PK in videomain. If not, rewrite query with proper values.

Comment: I checked every column... but still after this "WHERE newsvid.id = " . $video_id" query not recognized anything

Comment: dump the query and paste it here. Also, if you have a mysql error that will help!

Comment: SELECT newsvid.id, videoinformation.id, videomain.id, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.imgCover, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidQUality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidMaker, videoinformation.vidRoles, videoinformation.vidTime, videoinformation.imgShot1, videoinformation.imgShot2, videoinformation.imgShot3, videomain.vidMUrl FROM newsvid, videomain, videoinformation  WHERE newsvid.id = 1 AND videoinformation.id = 1 AND videomain.id = 1;

Comment: check L.E in my answer

Comment: please can you show me HOW i need to do same query BUT instead of 1 I need video_id because I'm using php <?php $video_id = $_GET['id']; ?> so i need video_id instead of 1 because content of the page depend on id.

Comment: check my answer again, please... and if you don't want the $video_id var there you can use $_GET['id'] but make sure that the value is indeed an video ID from DB table

Comment: I have foreign key (id) in videomain and videoinformation, primary key in newsvid and video_id take id from newsvid table...

Comment: modified my answer to fit your description... It's really hard for me to understand exactly what you are facing, and without proper debugging, I cannot help, I'm afraid...

Comment: you need to do some stuff: Check your apache error logs, check your db error logs for any possible error related with this. Afterwards, the query that you dumped, check it in phpmyadmin, run it separately and check to see if that throws any warning or error. And then, when you get something from debug, come here and post it. I will be able to assist ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables. Use double quotes. The variable will be okay. Use inner join like:

```
"SELECT newsvid.id, videoinformation.id, videomain.id, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.imgCover, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidQUality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidMaker, videoinformation.vidRoles, videoinformation.vidTime, videoinformation.imgShot1, videoinformation.imgShot2, videoinformation.imgShot3, videomain.vidMUrl 
FROM newsvid
INNER JOIN videomain
ON newsvid.id = videomain.id
INNER JOIN videoinformation
ON newsvid.id = videoinformation.id
WHERE newsvid.id = $video_is";
```